# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined angular animation

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, angular-animations

I'm trying to put **angular animation** at one of my users list. the list is created by **FOR Loop(*ngFor)**. Before the loop i use my trigger `[@listAnimation]="usersList.length"`.
the animation is working fine, But it gives an 
ERROR : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
to the Console. Why?

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="container" [@listAnimation]="usersList.length">
  <h1 class="h1 text-center mt-4" id="sectionHead">Users List</h1>

  <div *ngFor = "let user of usersList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 4, currentPage: p}">
    <div class="row mb-2 mx-auto" id="showUserList">

      <div class="col-sm-2 p-0 text-center">

        <img *ngIf="!user.avatar == ''" src="{{photoBaseUrl}}/{{user.avatar}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="user image" id="profilePic1">
        <img *ngIf="user.avatar == ''" src="{{photoBaseUrl}}/usergroup.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="user image" id="profilePic2">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p class="addPicText" routerLink="/uploadProfilePic/{{user._id}}">
            <i class="far fa-user addPhIcon"></i>
            <br> 
            Update
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="card-body py-0">
          <h5 class="card-title text-capitalize my-0 pt-1">{{user.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 font-sm">Email : {{user.email}}</p>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 font-sm">Phone : {{user.phone}}</p>
          <p class="card-text text-muted p-0 m-0 text-capitalize font-sm">Active : {{user.active}}</p>         
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3 pr-0 mr-0">
        <div class="w-75 mx-auto mt-2 text-uppercase">
          <p 
            routerLink="/editUser/{{user._id}}" 
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btnStyleSuccess font-xs m-0 p-1 mb-1">
            <i class="far fa-edit"></i> 
            Update
          </p>
          <p 
            (click)="openConfDialog(user._id)" 
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btnStyleDanger font-xs m-0 p-1">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> 
            Delete
          </p>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="text-center text-white mt-4">
    <pagination-controls class="userListPagination" (pageChange)="p =$event"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Animation Trigger :**

```
export let listAnimation =  trigger('listAnimation', [
        transition('* => *', [

        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), {optional: true}),

        query(':enter', stagger('50ms', [
            animate('300ms ease-in', keyframes([
              style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-30%)', offset: 0}),
              style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateX(0)',  offset: 0.3}),
              style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 1.0}),
        ]))]), {optional: true}),

        query(':leave', stagger('50ms', [
            animate('300ms ease-out', keyframes([
              style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', offset: 0}),
              style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateX(0)',  offset: 0.3}),
              style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-30%)',     offset: 1.0}),
            ]))]), {optional: true})
    ])
  ]);
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: because of while page init load, usersList have no data or it is not assigned.

Comment: as @UttamKukadiya said, so can you put the component code to point you to the issue?, maybe you just need to initialize it

Comment: this is the code : (below)

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.photoBaseUrl = '../../assets/images';    
  }`

Comment: `getUsers()
{
  this.auth.getUsersList().subscribe((data:any) => {
    if(data.success){
      this.usersList = data.users;     
    }
  })
}`

Comment: i already initialized it.